# How to create MAP Drive by batch file

Tags: batch-file, network-drive

often i have to create map drive where i specify machine and user credential. now i like to know can we write a batch file which will create map drive and where i provide all details like pc and folder location and user credentials etc. i got one as follows but i think this is not one which i require.
please guide me. thanks

```
net use \\<network-location>\<some-share>\ password /USER:username

@echo Create new L: drive mapping
@net use L: \\network path /persistent:yes
@echo Create new K: drive mapping
@net use K: \\network path /persistent:yes
:exit
```

if i do this way...then does it work

```
net use y: \\192.168.7.15\$D\testfolder password /USER:username  /PERSISTENT:YES
```

please guide.....the syntax is ok?

Comment: Is your batch file not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: i have to pass user id and password but do not know the syntax

Comment: first i want to check if the map drive Z is exist then delete it and then create a new map drive called Z with credentials. so need help.

Comment: tell me my second one syntax is ok?

Comment: Have you tried what you have? Does it work? If not, what is the error? From a command prompt, type `NET USE /?` to get the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer of the Mou's query:** If a map drive called Z exist in that pc then what will happen? can we write batch file like if a specific map drive exist then disconnect it and reconnect it again.

The solution of this problem is that You can simply map the share without assigning a drive letter. It is then mapped anonymously, only by its remote UNC path. This way you can also remove the mapping by specifiying only its remote name.

```
@echo off
net use \\192.168.7.15\testfolder password /user:domain\username /savecred /p:yes
REM Do your stuffs here.....
net use \\192.168.7.15\testfolder /delete
```

**Answer of the Thomas's query:** How to disconnect and connect map drive by batch file.

If you simply want to disconnect and re-connect a map drive, do like this:

```
@echo off
net use z: /delete
net use z: \\192.168.7.15\testfolder password /user:domain\username /savecred /p:yes
```

Answer (score 3):

I presume your testfolder is shared then do like this:

```
net use z: \\192.168.7.15\testfolder password /user:domain\username /savecred /p:yes
```

Comment: if a map drive called Z exist in that pc then what will happen? can we write batch file like if a specific map drive exist then disconnect it and reconnect it again?

Comment: can u tell me how to disconnect and connect map drive by batch file.

Comment: @Thomas..Please see my second answer.