# Include credentials of shared folder in WinSCP script file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, ftp, winscp, ftps

In order to access a remote shared folder, I need to indicate the username and password. However, I have no idea where to put it in my WinSCP code.

```
open ftps://ftpuser:password@hostname/ -explicit -certificate="key"
cd Results
lcd \\networkname\sharedfolder\folder\ 
put *
```

This produces an error which is:

> Error changing directory to '...'.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: `user` command and you'll be prompted for username. `pass` command and you'll be prompted for password.

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/A3_FTP_RFCs.html for a list of commands (under the section FTP commands).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error *"Error changing directory"*, which you are getting is most probably caused by the [`lcd` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_lcd). In Windows, the current working directory cannot be an UNC path (the `\\networkname`).

Instead of changing the current working directory, upload the file using a full path:

```
open ftps://ftpuser:password@hostname/ -explicit -certificate="key"
cd Results
put \\networkname\sharedfolder\folder\*
```

---

However if you actually need credentials for accessing the UNC path (the `\\networkname`), you have to authenticate prior to running the WinSCP script.

The batch file will be like:

```
net use \\networkname\sharedfolder password /user:domain\username /savecred /p:yes

winscp.com /script=... /log=...

net use \\networkname\sharedfolder /delete
```

Credits: [How to create MAP Drive by batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294761/850848).

You still need to use the full path with the [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put), instead of the `lcd` though. Unless you map the UNC path to a drive letter.